# difference between javascript consecutive if() if() statements and nested if statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement

I am working on a React project implementing Conway's game of life that has the following code

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            let count = 0;

            if (i > 0)
                if (g1[i - 1][j]) count++;
            if (i > 0 && j > 0)
                if (g1[i - 1][j - 1]) count++;
            if (i > 0 && j < this.cols - 1)
                if (g1[i - 1][j + 1]) count++;
            .......
```

and many lines after that are similar to the format above, the function is supposed to calculate the number of neighbours a cell has in a 30*50 grid by. The above code works fine but however when I try something like the following code, the program doesn't work.

```
    for (let i = 0; i < this.rows; i++) {
        for (let j = 0; j < this.cols; j++) {
            let count = 0;

            if(i>0){
                if(g1[i-1][j]){
                    count++
                }
            }
            if(i>0 && j >0){
                if(g1[i-1][j-1]){
                    count++
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I assume it is because the second statement is much less efficient than the previous one? Or is there something really wrong with the second that I completely missed? Is there any specific difference between the two different if methods? Are you allowed to use if statements without {} in ES6?

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work ? Do you have an error ? Wrong results ?

Comment: You can use `if` statements without `{}`, provided the code is only single line, so something like `if (some condition) count++;` works. If you need to execute multiple lines of code, its much better and cleaner to keep it within `{}`.

Comment: There were no errors but the page just reloads forever and even though it complies, the cells never change when the first method works fine. Any insights?

Comment: While it is definitely acceptable in JS to write single line `if` bodies without surrounding curly braces, I would encourage you to follow the recommendation of Douglas Crockford of "JavaScript: The Good Parts" fame and just [always wrap control flow structures in curly braces](https://www.crockford.com/javascript/code.html#compound%20statements).

Comment: your code *implies* that you've taken the first two "first level" if's, and ignored the `many lines after that` - thereby changing the logic altogether - if, all you did was place `{}` in appropriate places without simply dropping lines like you code suggests, then there's no reason this change would cause the behaviour to change, clearly you've changes something else as well

Answer (score 0):

Both code blocks are pretty much the same.  In JS if you don't use the curly brackets to wrap your if statements, it executes the next line (and only the next line) if the condition is true -- before moving onto the rest of the code.

```js
if( 3+2 == 5 ){
  console.log( 'test - 1' );
}

if( 3+2 == 5 )
  console.log( 'test - 2' );

if( 10 > 7 )
  if( 7 < 14  ) console.log( 'test - 3' );
  
if( 10 > 7 ){
  if( 7 < 14 ){
    console.log( 'test - 4' );
  }
}

if( 3*7 === 14 )
  console.log( 'test - 5' ); // should not run
  console.log( 'test - 6' ); // this should run
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function testIt(){
    a = 5; b = 6; c = 0; d = 0;
    if(b>a)
        if(a<b) c++; d++;
        d++;
    if(b<a)
        if(a<b) c++; d++;
        d++;
    if(b>a)
        if(a>b) c++; d++;
        d++;
    console.log(d === 6);
}
```

>true

As ugly as that is, d++ always executes regardless of the conditional.  If you're trying to hand modify a big pile of code that looks like that, you probably want to break it up and test the pieces one by one.

Maybe if it ain't broke, don't fix it?